# How to use large database (Sqlite more than 100 MB) in android application?

Tags: android, sqlite

i develop one application in which require sqlite database. Database size is very large approx. 100 Mb.

so i have not any idea which way use these database in my application.
database is some private contents so not installed in sdcard...

1. Can android app support or store 100MB database in data directory ?
2. If app store database in sdcard then , any other way to implement so user can not see or used these database ?
3. How to encode my sqlite database and store in device so user can not used these database ?

Please anyone suggest me if any idea related to large database.

Comment: just a thought - consider storing some of this data on a web server so it doesn't use up the entire sdcard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u can store the database file in the data directory. There is no such restriction on the size of file in Android I suppose. At least I have never read about any such restriction.